# On spectral multiplicity of left shift operators

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $U$ be an operator defined on $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ by $U(e_{n})=e_{n-1}$, where $e_{n}$ is an orthonormal basis of $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$. $U$ is a left shift operator. Since $U$ is unitary operator so spectrum is on $S^{1}$. What is spectral measure of $U$? What is its spectral  decomposition with respect to multiplicity? Further, suppose T is a self-adjoint operator in B(H) with σ(T) is  spectrum of T. μ is a spectral measure. For the operators having general continuous spectrum how to calculate the multiplicity function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ with the space of square summable Fourier series $f(z)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_n z^n$, $\sum |a_n|^2<\infty$, on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}=\{z:|z|=1\}$. It is the space $L^2(\mathbb{T},\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on the circle and the operator $U$ maps the function $f(z)$ to $z^{-1}f(z)$. It is the spectral decomposition.

Comment: I don't know every time I am asking a question, people giving negative votes. I wanted to learn from experts over here. What is the problem with Overflowadmin

Comment: Probably people do not consider them being of research level? Try to use math.stackexchange

Comment: Yaa, sorry, But I already posted this in math stack exchange, after two days I was not getting an answer so I put it here. Please unblock me for giving questions

Comment: You could mention this in the question